# Bonding 3 10mbps adsl lines with a mikrotik

Tags: networking

How do I get it right cause it uses all three lines for upload , but only uses two for download ?

Please help

Pieter

Answer (score 0):

The question is, if your ISP is supporting the bonded lines.

Most 'bonding' routers would simply load balance accross the three connections. Therefore, you simply wont achieve the sum bandwith.

Answer (score 0):

Steven is correct here. There are two scenarios:

1. You buy 3x independent links from your ISP, each with its own WAN address, and bond them locally.
2. You buy a bonded link from the ISP which gives you a single logical link. This is usually only done in pairs.

In scenario 1 your traffic can only really use 1 path at a time, so if you have 20 tcp connections they'll distribute but say a single FTP download can only use one link. In scenario 2 that same single connection can use the entire sum bandwidth - overhead.